# Pretty Printing Parentheses

Tags: atomic-code-golf, whitespace, balanced-string

The worst part about long lines or code or math equations are the parentheses. Nobody wants to read through `2x(3y+4*abs(x^[2*e^x])-5{3(x+y)-5})`!

So, the goal of this challenge is to make it at least slightly easier to read these parentheses-filled beasts! For the above math equation, the output should be:

```
2x (
  3y+4*abs (
    x^ [
      2*e^x
    ]
  )
  -5 {
    3 (
      x+y
    )
    -5
  }
)
```

A parenthesis is defined as either of these characters: `()[]{}`. Indents should each be two spaces, and there should be one space of seperation between the expression and the parenthesis: `2x (`, `x^ [` as some examples.

I would like to debut the [Atomic Code Golf metric](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/403/new-code-golf-metric-atomic-code-golf) in this question. Take out all separators in your code (`()[]{}. ;` to name some common ones), and then take the length of your program if every reserved word and operator were 1 character long. That is your program's score.  `if x**(3.2)==b[3]:print x` is 11 points: `if|x|**|3|.|2|==|b|3|print|x`, or `ix*3.2=b3px`. Any quick questions about the metric can be posted here; larger questions should be discussed in meta using the link above.

Lowest score wins. Good luck, have fun!

Comment: Is `$x` one token or two?

Comment: @mob: Depends on what `$x` is: if it's a variable, 1 token. If it's a math operator, then 2.

Comment: Love the scoring system, I think it will make Common Lisp much more viable.

Comment: Re. the task itself: do we have to check for matching brackets, or is it okay to assume that they are all correctly matched up?  Furthermore, is the input expression guaranteed to contain no whitespace already? (In particular, in the vicinity of the parens..)

Comment: @FireFly: They're all correctly matched (there will be as many open brackets as there are closed brackets). Yes, there will be no whitespace.

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3088/indent-a-string-using-given-parentheses) (The differences being that the other question asks for K&R style bracket placement and that it's plain code golf.)

Comment: The unary answer will win.

Comment: Are names from standard libraries considered "reserved words"?

Comment: I've voted to close this as unclear as the challenge body does not properly specify what counts as a "separator"

Comment: Was this sandboxed?  There are plenty of languages that can easily write programs consisting of only characters on your "common separator" list.

Comment: @WheatWizard This was asked in 2013, so I think it's unlikely it was sandboxed (given that sandboxes really started in 2014)

Comment: @ChartZBelatedly Oh for some reason I thought it was asked today.  It looked very reminiscent of old challenges.

Answer (score 4):

### C, <strike>139</strike> 137 chars, 67 tokens

```
i,n;                                                      // 2 tokens
main(c){                                                  // 2 tokens
        while(~(c=getchar()))                             // 5 tokens
                n=strchr("([{}])",c)?                     // 11 tokens
                        n=c%4!=1,                         // 7 tokens
                        i+=n*4-2,                         // 7 tokens
                        printf("\n%*s%c"+n,n?1:i,"",c)    // 15 tokens
                :                                         // 1 token
                        !printf("\n%*s%3$c"+!n*4,i,"",c); // 17 tokens
}
```

Logic:

- Read until EOF (detect it because `~EOF==0`).
- If parenthesis, check open/close (for `c` in `")]}"`, `c%4==1`), update indentation (`i`), print with some whitespace.
- If not, print the character, possibly prefixed by newline and indentation (`n` is true after parenthesis).

Comment: Whatever it is you're doing with `n` looks truly evil. :) Woah!: `c%4!=1`! That's brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 102(?) Tokens

(Please correct if I didn't count correctly)

```
def f(t):
#1  2 3
    l,s,p,c,e,n=0,"",1," ",")]}","\n"
#   4 5 6 7 8 9ab cd e fgh ijklm no p
    for i in t:
#   q   r s  t
        if i in"([{": l+=2;s+=c+i+n+l*c
#       u  v w xyzAB  CD E FG HIJKLMNOP
        elif i in e: l-=2;s+=n+l*c+i+p*(n+l*c);p=1
#       Q    R S  T  UV W XY Z123456789 abcde  fgh
        else:
#       i
            if len(s) and s[-1]in e: s+=n+l*c
#           j  k   l  m   n  o p  q  rs tuvwx
            s+=i;p=0
#           yz A BCD
    return s
#   E      F
```

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 86 char

57 tokens? (21+25+5+3+1+2?) Newlines are significant.

```
s![[{()}\]]!1-(3&ord$&)?" $&
"."  "x++$x:$/.($y="  "x--$x)."$&
$y"!ge;s/
 *
/
/g;print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>76</s> 74

```javascript
(a,d)=>(d=0)||a.replaceAll(/[(\[{]/g,b=>` ${b}\n`+'  '.repeat(++d)).replaceAll(/[)\]}]/g,b=>`\n${(f='  '.repeat(--d))+b}\n${f}`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BboJAEIbvPMUcTNgtII22TROCSQ8eempSexONCwy4zbpLdlcLQZ6dQqONzmky/3xf/m92YibTvLLB6bUPQ7B7boAJjSxvAGturAEuYbl6AX6oBB5QWma5kj6kRwtS2TH@ev9wVlZzWU4rrayyTYVTjZVgGb4JATEUR5mNGDHIdLb34ZKOPgqtA8OcmAbLdIl2AMYi0d9Zoz1qeUmuViLxBz6xXNbVv9ItXXovjpwucpwi7gnzcxovSB4/0vOZ3XQj4Zok63YTln4aL3YwadMukTvPBXDHN2SWeF5O6T1Dk013ZRI5aUkR3xJBMBDeaJq0RbejfZQpaZTAqVAlKYg7q8m88Z4eWGpIvV3PHnBbb2jw3M5J7TXD0lGX0v4X)

```javascript
(a,d)=>               pas argument a and d (a is the string, d is just as decleration)
 (d=0)||               set d to 0
 a.replaceAll(         replace everything in a that matches....
   /[(\[{]/g,            [,(,{   with....
   b=>                   pass matches into function
     ` ${b}\n`             space, bracket(the match) and newline
     +'  '.repeat(++d)     increment d and repeat the 2 spaces d times
   )
 .replaceAll(/[)\]}]/g,  match all ),],} and replace them with....
    b=>                  pass matches into function
      `\n${(f='  '.repeat(--d))+b}\n${f}`   newline, decrement d and repeat the 2 spaces d times, closing bracket(the match), newline and once again the repeated spaces
)
```

results in

```javascript
#a#,#d#=>#d#=#0#||#a#replaceAll#/#[#(#\#[#{#]#/#g#b#=>#`# #$#{#b#}#\#n#`#+#'# # #'#repeat#++#d#replaceAll#/#[#)#\#]#}#]#/#g#b#=>#`#\#n#$#{#f#=#'# # #'#r#e#p#e#a#t#--#d#+#b#}#\#n#$#{#f#}#`#
```

Comment: You can probably remove the braces `{}` inside the backticks

Comment: @Wezl , i am not so sure about those, as he specified only sperators, not sure if these are sperators.